# Is there software that will track electronic component inventory WITH serial number tracking?

Tags: inventory

I'm using Partkeepr on my server to keep track of my pile of electronics, but I just ran into a situation for which there is no feature:

Let's say you have 10 NodeMCUs, a few Wemos D1 Minis, two or three ESP32s, etc.

The following features need to exist, or I need to find them in some other software:

1. Kits.  Being able to take 5 of something to make 1 of something else, decrease each of the 5 items by 1 and increase the manufactured result by 1.  Basic manufacturing inventory management.
2. Serial number tracking.  It's easy to track that you added 5 Wemos D1 Minis to your electronics collection.  But, that is one of those components that has a unique identifier, the MAC Address, which could double as the serial number.  If I have 5 Wemos D1's that's great, but which one did I just remove from my stock to make something, and how do I create a serial number for the final manufactured part so I can look that up to see what components are in it?
3. Deployment.  I just created a widget using 5 components.  Where is it deployed?  What is its IP address, what software did I flash it with (version, etc.)  This would all have to be recorded on the manufactured item's detail table.
4. Individual item condition.  Is this Wemos D1 Mini new?  Has it been flashed?  Are there any notes about it, like "needs repair", or "antenna not included."  Again, this would be individual serial number dependent.

Anyone know of anything that can do this?